# Is there a way of using the main module heap from a dll or if not safely deleting allocations made in a dll from the main module (app)

Tags: c++, dll, heap-memory

I have a class in the main module that holds a list of stuff. I'd like to add some stuff to that list in a dll. Items in the list could be added and removed (allocated/deallocated) arbitrarily.

My understanding is that it's bad form to delete data allocated in one module from another. Can I somehow allocate data using the main module heap from a dll?  If not, is there a safe way to delete data allocated in a dll from the main module?

Ideally, a solution would work on both Linux and Windows.  Here's an example (that works) in Windows.

Notice that in Main.cpp I'm deleting an allocation made in the DynamicModule dll and Windows doesn't throw any exceptions. I was expecting one, thinking that the main module shouldn't be able to delete an allocation made on the dll's heap.

```
// Main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "LibClass.h"
typedef void (*DLLFunc)(LibClass*);
DLLFunc dllFunc;
HMODULE LoadDynamicLib()
{
    std::string libPath("Release/DynamicModule.dll");
    const size_t cSize = strlen(libPath.c_str()) + 1;
    wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[cSize];
    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, wc, cSize, libPath.c_str(), cSize - 1);
    HMODULE handle = LoadLibrary(wc);
    assert(handle != 0);
    delete[] wc;
    dllFunc = reinterpret_cast<DLLFunc>(GetProcAddress(handle, "AddNames"));
    return handle;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HMODULE handle = LoadDynamicLib();
    LibClass lib;
    float *firstVal = new float(1.0f);
    lib.values.push_back(firstVal);
    if (handle) dllFunc(&lib);
    delete lib.values[1];
    lib.values.pop_back();
    lib.values.clear(); // does this dealloc items or just removes them??
    FreeLibrary(handle);
    return 0;
}

// LibClass.h
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#ifdef _WINDLL
#define LIBAPI  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBAPI  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
struct LibClass {
    std::vector<float*> values;
};

// DynamicModule.cpp
#include "../testcppdll/LibClass.h"
extern "C"
{
    LIBAPI void AddNames(LibClass *_libClass) {
        if (_libClass) {
            float* newStr = new float(3.0f);
            _libClass->values.push_back(newStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem with create/destroy dll functions is that if the list lives in a data type that might automatically reallocate depending on the growth of items (certainly with unordered_map), it might be hard to catch and deal with it.

Comment: That can be quite risky, yes.  The failure mode is rebuilding, say, the main project with a new version of the compiler and runtime library but not the library project.  Not just because the new version might be using a different allocator, the std::string or std::vector implementations might have changed.  Ugly memory corruption is the result. 
 Never an issue when you first start the project, but big issue years later when the victim programmer can't email you anymore to ask you for an update of the library.  If you can be sure that both are always built together then it is not an issue.

Comment: @AlexF, any better suggestion for a dll interface? A linked list?